# Cannot Read property of 'store' undefined . While Using Redux-toolkit in a React Native App. Can Anyone tell whats the problem here

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying to fetch data into my store using createAsyncThunk() in React Native Application.
But getting an error of Cannot Read property of 'store' undefined. I am new in the React eco-system was trying to learn React Native and trying to use redux-toolkit in react- native. My app ran fine for the simple Counter increment/decrement actions. But when I tried to fetch data to my store using createAsyncThunk() method , my App is showing error of Cannot Read property of 'store' undefined. I could not find whats the erorr . Any help will appreciated.

```
const App =  ()=>{
  return (
    <Provider store = {store}>
       <Counter/>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer : {
        posts : postReducer ,
    }
})


const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';


const initialState = {
    data: null,
    error: {},
    isLoading : true,
};

 const getPosts = createAsyncThunk(
    'post/getPosts',
    async (name , thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios(url);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error){
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('Fetching unsuccesful');
        }
    }
);

const postSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'posts',
    initialState,
    reducers : {},
    extraReducers : {
        [getPosts.pending] : (state) =>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        },
        [getPosts.fulfilled] : (state,action) =>{
            state.data = action.payload;
            state.isLoading = false; 
        },
        [getPosts.rejected] : (state,action) =>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.error = action.payload;
        }
    }
})
console.log(postSlice);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: make sure `store` is not undefined, try `console.log(store)` to check it

Comment: Please add the code where you want to access the store.